# VNC Connection error "Unable to connect to VNC Server using your chosen security setting."

Tags: server, security, vnc

When I use Real VNC on mac and connect to my Ubuntu minimal dedicated server that I rent I get this message:

> Unable to connect to VNC Server using your chosen security setting. Either upgrade VNC Server to a more recent version from RealVNC, or select a weaker level of encryption.

Any ideas?

I tried changing the encryption level and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your system is *way* out of date.

SSH into it, and run this command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

From there, you want to actually upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04, because your current version is no longer supported. Do this by running:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and answering all the questions it has.

From there, the system should get the latest versions of the VNC server and ensure everything is shiny and new.

***Now, it is important to note that you are not playing securely!*** VNC is *not* a safe protocol at all, especially at Encryption Level 0. In effect, anyone on the network (or potentially the internet) can see what you're doing now. That's not good. Fortunately, you can use something known as [SSH tunneling](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-tunneling-on-a-vps) to securely tunnel VNC traffic.